# Getting realtime memory utilization data from vsphere API using python scripts

Tags: python, api, vsphere

I'm trying to get realtime memory and bandwidth utilization data from the vsphere API using the python library pyvmomi.py. So far I've only managed to get data of the resources allocated to VMs. And cant seem to find any way to get realtime utillization of all the VMs running. I've added a part of my code below to convey what functions I'm using. Looking for ideas on how I can get realtime stats. Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
print(c.CurrentTime())
searcher = c.content.searchIndex
vm = searcher.FindByIp(ip='10.0.10.54', vmSearch=True)
print("VM name: ", vm.config.name)
print("VM Guest OS:")
print(vm.config.guestFullName)
print("Location:")
print(vm.config.files.snapshotDirectory)
print("VM numCPU:")
print(vm.config.hardware.numCPU)
print("VM number of cores:")
print(vm.config.hardware.numCoresPerSocket)
print("RAM:")
print(vm.config.hardware.memoryMB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those properties aren't available directly against the VM object itself. You'll have to use the PerformanceManager in order to pull specific metrics.

Here's an example that should be able to help you get started figuring out what metrics are available as well as how to start pulling them for your script: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/vm_perf_example.py